# Kivy dynamic widget issue

Tags: python, kivy

Well, i'm a beginner using kivy framework, so i thought that someone here could help me.
My question is:
On my app, the user input a number n, then the app return n TextInput widgets. But how can i use the values inserted on each TextInput? The first part is easy to do, i did it by a list. (If someone know how to do it directly on kv file i would appreciate it). My issue is on second part, i need to use and manipulate these values (in TextInputs) later but i can't reach to them. I mean, i set up for each widget in the list an id, but i can't reach to .text attribute of them. Here is a piece of my code:

```
class FirstLayout(BoxLayout):

   def next_layout(self):  
   self.clear_widgets()  
   secondLayout = Factory.SecondLayout()  
   number = NumericProperty()  
# This 'number' variable came from another widget on kv file

   textinput_list = []
# That list will receive as many TextInputs field as my variable 'number' said (by the loop for)

   for i in range(int(self.number.text)):
        textinput_list.append(TextInput())
        textinput_list[i].id = "input" + str(i + 1)
    # So for each textinput, i added a id named 'inputx' (where x is the number of the current
    # iteration) my question resides here. How could i use those values (inside of each textinput 
    # on this list
    # later? Because i'm not creating these widgets (TextInputs) on kv language so i don't know how to
    # bind the ids for a new variable directly in .py file
        secondLayout.container.add_widget(textinput_list[i]) 

    self.add_widget(secondLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you just have to make `textinput_list` a class variable. So this.

```
textinput_list = []
```

becomes

```
self.textinput_list = []
```

Lets say you have an object of FirstLayout called first. With `first.textinput_list[0]` you can access the first textinput and so on.

If you want to easily access the textinputs via id I would suggest using a dictionary, with the keys being the id's and the values being the inputs.

Comment: Strictly speaking one would call that an instance variable, see also the [documentation on class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).